¿Cómo puedo incluir un código dentro de otro código de modo que tenga la misma funcionalidad?
Estoy creando un botón que me permita añadir menus a una página que administra un contenido, ya pensé en como funcionaría añadiendo la parte HTML con php y me falta un detalle del que me acabo de dar cuenta, mi menú es desplegable y tiene la siguiente estructura:
$(".btn_menu").on('click', function () {
            var menu = $(this).prop('id');
            switch (menu) {
                case "btn_flow":
                    $(".menus").slideUp();
                    $("#casos_flow").slideDown();
                    break;
                case "btn_ftth":
                    $(".menus").slideUp();
                    $("#casos_ftth").slideDown();
                    break;
                case "btn_dth":
                    $(".menus").slideUp();
                    $("#casos_dth").slideDown();
                    break;
            }

A medida que se incluyan más menus deben incluirse más case al switch, al incluir la estructura en html pensé en separar los menus existentes en otro archivo e incluirlos en el index.php con include("menu.php"); para que así se escriba en el menú sin afectar al index pero el switch está en el index y ya intenté que funcionara llamando la función desde un archivo funciones.js ¿Cómo puedo incluir más "case" a medida que incluyo los menus sin que malogre el funcionamiento de mi código?

Refactoriza tu código. En lugar de tener decenas de case, haz que los string en cuestión sean parametrizables. Lo único que cambia entre uno y otro es btn por casos.

sugieres cambiar el switch por un else if para añadirlo al final del codigo cada vez que añado un nuevo menu?

No, leé de nuevo: la palabra clave es parametrizar.
